# Plank is not working

Tags: gnome, android, make, google, 23.10

When I run `sudo -sE plank --preferences`, I get this error:

```
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.467712] [Wnck] wnck_set_client_type: changing the client type is not supported.
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.657446] [DBusManager:192] Not able to register our interfaces
[WARN 17:20:46.835039] Unable to get org.ayatana.bamf matcher: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.845754] [GLib-GIO] g_dbus_proxy_set_default_timeout: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.847881] [GLib-GObject] invalid (NULL) pointer instance
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.855566] [GLib-GObject] g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.856311] [GLib-GObject] invalid (NULL) pointer instance
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.863369] [GLib-GObject] g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.864505] [GLib-GObject] invalid (NULL) pointer instance
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.876638] [GLib-GObject] g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.881086] [GLib-GObject] invalid (NULL) pointer instance
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.901080] [GLib-GObject] g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.906745] [GLib-GObject] invalid (NULL) pointer instance
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.921482] [GLib-GObject] g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.925686] [GLib-GObject] invalid (NULL) pointer instance
[CRITICAL 17:20:46.949178] [GLib-GObject] g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.026481] [GLib-GIO] g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
[WARN 17:20:47.031967] Failed to get running applications: 
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.044740] [GLib] g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
[WARN 17:20:47.070961] (Services/Matcher.c:299):plank_matcher_active_launchers: runtime check failed: (_tmp3_ != NULL)
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.086230] [GLib-GIO] g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
[WARN 17:20:47.088750] Failed to register favorites: 
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.096418] [GLib] g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
[WARN 17:20:47.128244] [Unity:92] Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)
[WARN 17:20:47.146052] [Unity:92] Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.859280] [GLib-GIO] GFileInfo created without standard::is-hidden
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.868433] [GLib-GIO] file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1633 (g_file_info_get_is_hidden): should not be reached
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.871939] [GLib-GIO] GFileInfo created without standard::is-hidden
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.880743] [GLib-GIO] file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1633 (g_file_info_get_is_hidden): should not be reached
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.883607] [GLib-GIO] GFileInfo created without standard::is-hidden
[CRITICAL 17:20:47.892806] [GLib-GIO] file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1633 (g_file_info_get_is_hidden): should not be reached

(plank:24667): dconf-WARNING **: 17:20:50.162: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)
[WARN 17:21:03.258711] Creating surface took WAY TOO LONG (37ms), enabled downscaling for this cache!

(plank:24667): dconf-WARNING **: 17:21:08.130: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(plank:24667): dconf-WARNING **: 17:21:10.387: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)
```

Why am I getting this error, what does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are you trying to run `plank` with `sudo` ?